# Method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, html, flask

```
from flask import *
from flask_restful import *
import sqlite3
import database


@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    """ hanldes the admin page for user entry """

    db = database.database()
    db.create()
    db.table('admin')
    #data = db.print_database('admin')
    #return render_template ("mylogin.html", input = 'admin', dbs = data.fetchall())
    return render_template ("mylogin.html", input = 'admin')

@app.route('/admin', methods = ["POST"])
def admin_post():
    """ hanldes the admin page for user entry """
    print "handling post"
    return request.form['text']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML CODE : I have not posted the entire code here as not deviate from the issue I am facing. I am able to open the /admin page and when I give an input , getting an error "Method is not allowed for the requested URL"

```
<h2>welcome admin</h2>
<form action="." method ="POST">
    hello admin
    <input type = "text" name = "text">
    <input type = "submit" name ="my-form" value = "Send">
</form>
```

Comment: adding the HTML code :  <h2>welcome admin</h2>
  <form action="." method ="POST">
        hello admin
        <input type = "text" name = "text">
        <input type = "submit" name ="my-form" value = "Send">
  </form>

Comment: @frlan why not mark HTML code as well?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Easy one: overseen that it was ment as source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
<h2>welcome admin</h2>
<form action="{{ url_for('admin_post') }}" method ="POST">
   <input type = "text" name = "text">
   <input type = "submit" name ="my-form" value = "Send">
</form>
```

What you're basically doing is sending the form to your ***admin*** function which only accepts **GET** requests.

You need to post your form to the ***admin_post*** function which accepts **POST** requests.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: how to do I do that ? Any option to enable that ?

Comment: There's a tick mark to the left of the answer, by clicking on that, you choose the answer. And by clicking on the up/down arrows you vote up/down the answers.